# Datepicker Alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular9

Open above of its own input element or sometimes vertically anywhere on page. I need that it should open  below input element.

[image]

[image]

now its overlay its own input element.

I find it may be the top issue in position function.

the following code:

```
  setElemPosition() {
      const rect = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (this.domele) {
         this.domele.style.position = 'absolute';
         this.domele.style.top = rect.top + this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
         this.domele.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
         this.domele.style.width = Math.floor(rect.width) + 'px';
         this.domele.style.zIndex = '9999999999';
      }
   }
```

Comment: Could you reproduce a [stackbltiz example?](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

Comment: No sorry. Do you have any idea about getBoundingClientRect() ?

Comment: It is resolved now. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just used **window.pageYOffset**. The issue get resolved and the alignment is now showing properly.

```
 setElemPosition() {
  const rect = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (this.domele) {
     this.domele.style.position = 'absolute';
     this.domele.style.top = rect.top + window.pageYOffset + this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
     this.domele.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
     this.domele.style.width = Math.floor(rect.width) + 'px';
     this.domele.style.zIndex = '9999999999';
  }
```